# Formatting html object to make card using css

Tags: html, css

So i'm working on a project and i'm having some trouble with the css/formatting since I've never heavily used css before.

Below is a code snippet. in the snippet the text is kinda far below the image. i need it to be the same height as the image and have the same line spacing between lines (right now bettween the bold text and the regular text there is a large space) as well as prevent the text from wrapping under the image.

[See this link for example of how I need the css to make this look.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BqhVh.jpg)

I'm not sure how exactly to do this and any help would be greatly appreciated.

```html
<head>
  <style>
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
      /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
      /* This is not needed at this point */
      /*margin-top: -1px; */
      /* Prevent double borders: This is not needed at this point */
      background-color: #8a0707;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    /*******************************************/
    
    li {
      width: 30%;
      min-height: 5em;
      padding: 1.5em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      display: -moz-inline-stack;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 5px;
      zoom: 1;
      *display: inline;
      _height: 250px;
    }
    /*******************************************/
    /*these attributes only work if the object is a div with the chip class*/
    /*.chip {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
*/
    
    .chip img {
      float: left;
      /* Moves the chip image to a particular side */
      margin: -1.5em .5em 2em 0em;
      /*moves image down ,moves text next to image rightwards,moves image up, moves image right*/
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">


    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div class="chip" style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>




  </ul>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `.chip` class associated with any HTML element in your code,
remove `.chip` from your stylesheet, remove it from here

```
.chip img {
  float: left;
  /* Moves the chip image to a particular side */
  margin: 0em .5em 2em 0em;
  /*moves image down ,moves text next to image rightwards,moves image up, moves image right*/
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Then rerun your code , it works fine.
Here is the [Codepen](https://codepen.io/animaxf/pen/jGNZjp)

Comment: I edited the code so I actually use chip. I grabbed the wrong code snippet before. I use chip now, but It still has weird spacing and when the code snippet is run, the text wraps under the image which I don't want.

Comment: try to change margin on img element.

Comment: I did that and it works for stopping the text from wrapping around the bottom, but I still have spacing issues. The h4 and the other text need to move up so the top of the h4 is the same height as the top of the img. and the line spacing is still weird

Answer (score 0):

Start with adding:

```
img {
    float: left;
}
```

And go from there...

Answer (score 0):

```html
<head>
  <style>
    img{float: left;}
    * {
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
    
    #myInput {
      background-image: url('/css/searchicon.png');
      background-position: 10px 12px;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      width: 100%;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 12px 20px 12px 40px;
      border: 1px solid #ddd;
      margin-bottom: 12px;
    }
    
    #myUL {
      list-style-type: none;
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
    }
    
    #myUL li a {
      /*border: 1px solid #ddd;*/
      /* This is not needed at this point */
      /*margin-top: -1px; */
      /* Prevent double borders: This is not needed at this point */
      background-color: #8a0707;
      padding: 12px;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-size: 18px;
      color: black;
      display: block
    }
    
    #myUL li a:hover:not(.header) {
      background-color: #eee;
    }
    /*******************************************/
    
    li {
      width: 30%;
      min-height: 5em;
      padding: 1.5em;
      border: 1px solid #000;
      display: -moz-inline-stack;
      display: inline-block;
      vertical-align: top;
      margin: 5px;
      zoom: 1;
      *display: inline;
      _height: 250px;
    }
    /*******************************************/
    /*these attributes only work if the object is a div with the chip class*/
    /*.chip {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 25px;
    height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    line-height: 50px;
    border-radius: 25px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}
*/
    
    .chip img {
      float: left;
      /* Moves the chip image to a particular side */
      margin: 0em .5em 2em 0em;
      /*moves image down ,moves text next to image rightwards,moves image up, moves image right*/
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      display: inline-block;
      border-radius: 50%;
    }
  </style>

  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <h2>My Phonebook</h2>

  <input type="text" id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">

  <ul id="myUL">


    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>

    <li>
      <div style="vertical-align:top;">
        <img src="http://farm4.static.flickr.com/3623/3279671785_d1f2e665b6_s.jpg" alt="lobster" width="75" height="75" />
        <h4>froodle</h4>
        Moodle Get access to course materials and assignemnts and foster active learning, understanding and collaboration.
      </div>
    </li>




  </ul>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var input, filter, ul, li, a, i;
      input = document.getElementById("myInput");
      filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
      ul = document.getElementById("myUL");
      li = ul.getElementsByTagName("li");

      for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
        a = li[i].getElementsByTagName("h4")[0];
        if (a.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
          li[i].style.display = "";
        } else {
          li[i].style.display = "none";

        }
      }
    }
  </script>

</body>
```

Float left on image and limit text height to fit image height.